# I am getting the error unreconized function or variable 'grade' in line 20 " xlswrite(filename,grade,sheet,xlwriterange) " how can i fix this?

Tags: matlab

```
clear all; clc;format long;
filename = 'myexcel.xlsx'; 
sheet = 1;
xlReadRange = 'A1:A6';
xlWriteRange = 'B1:B6'; 
scores = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlReadRange); 
for i=1:length(scores)
if(scores(i)>=90 && scores(i)<=100)
grade(i,1)= {'A'};
elseif(scores(i)>=80 && scores(i)<90)
grade(i,1)= {'B'};
elseif(scores(i)>=70 && scores(i)<80)
grade(i,1)= {'C'};
elseif(scores(i)>=60 && scores(i)<70)
grade(i,1)= {'D'};
else
grade(i,1)= {'F'};
end
end
xlswrite(filename,grade,sheet,xlWriteRange)
```

I have looked up the error and cannot find a solution to the problem unreconized function or variable 'grade' in line 20 " xlswrite(filename,grade,sheet,xlwriterange) "

Comment: Do not tag spam please. This has nothing to do with deployment, nor with the MATLAB GUI Design Editor.

Comment: Given you have an `else` clause, the only thing that can happen to cause this error is that your `scores` is empty, causing the entire `for` loop to be skipped. Apparently this is not the way to import your Excel sheet.